# Writing byte[] to file in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, file-io, xamarin, arrays

If i want to write byte[] in C# desktop application, i write the following code:

```
byte[] content = ... // a lot of code

using(var  fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, System.FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    fileStream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
}
```

And it works fine. But when i tried to do this in Xamarin Android Application (pcl project) i was pretty surprised when discover that it does not work!. 
So how can i write data from byte array to some file in pcl project?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work.Are you getting any exception?

Comment: I mean that it this code not comliling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone does not support direct File IO operations, so any PCL that includes Windows Phone in it's profile will not support it either.  You can do File IO operations from a non-PCL Xamarin Android (or iOS) project.